# UICollectionView: Is there a way to reload only the supplementary views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have an uicollectionview with *supplementaryView* for each section.
 In each *supplementaryView* I have some buttons. 
In dataSource method *collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:* I'm setting the buttons tags with the *indexPath.section*. I made some delegate methods when a button is pressed and send the section(button.tag) as parameter.

Everything works fine, but here comes the problem:

- when I insert or delete a section it must update the buttons tags, but I don't want to reload all the items from each section.

I've tried:

- to get the supplementaryViews with the dataSource method *collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:* and call *layoutIfNeeded* method for each *supplementaryView*, in this way the *supplementaryViews* are reloading, but this approach multiply my *supplementaryViews*.
- a fast *for* in *collectionView.subviews* and get just the *supplementaryView* and call *layoutIfNeeded* method, but it doesn't reload, just the layout is reloading.
- *reloadSections:* method, but this reload all items from the section

Ohh.. And I use *NSFetchedResultsController*(delegate) for inserting and deleting sections.

Can anyone help me with this? Is there a way to reload only the *supplementaryView*? Is there other approach for this scenario?

Thank You!

Comment: I solved it. I use custom *UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* for my *supplementaryView* and one of the custom attribute is a *NSInteger* that keeps the section and in the NSFetchedResultsController delegate method *controllerDidChangeContent:* after inserting or deleting sections, I invalidate the collection view layout. I'm not sure if is best practice, but it works and time is important right now :)

Answer (score 12):

To reload supplementary views you can use `-invalidateLayoutWithContext:`.

See documentation for `UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext` and method `-invalidateSupplementaryElementsOfKind:atIndexPaths:` (available since iOS 8).

Comment: [`invalidateSupplementaryElementsOfKind`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext/invalidateSupplementaryElementsOfKind:atIndexPaths:) is available on iOS 8 and higer.

Comment: It was an old question, but good to know for future similar situations. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea how I can get the supplementary view reload to animate with invalidLayout?

Comment: This doesn't actually seem to trigger the `collectionView(_:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:)` API

Answer (score 9):

Instead of reloading these views, getting a reference to each visible supplementary view so that you can change the tag might be sufficient for your needs.

There is a simple method you can use to do this:

`let supplementaryViews = collectionView.visibleSupplementaryViews(ofKind: "identifier")`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618026-visiblesupplementaryviews