# Crash on collectionView.performBatchUpdates when trying to hide footer/header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, collectionview

I get the data from API that divided into pages, I user `var hasMoreUsers: Bool` to show/hide the footer cell

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    if hasMoreUsers {
        return CGSizeMake(collectionView.contentSize.width, 50)
    } else {
        return CGSizeZero
    }
}
```

The code brake on the last page where I set `hasMoreUsers = false` and calling `self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates` to add the data

**Here is the error**

Got this error at line calling `self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates`

`*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44/UICollectionViewData.m:884`

Follow by

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for -layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter at path <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'`

Look like it need dimension for footer, but I already return `CGSizeZero` for it and this should be the problem. Really confuse.

Answer (score 5):

Supply a non-zero size, such as `CGSizeMake(0.01, 0.01)`

This appears to be a bug in `UICollectionView`. Even though the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForFooterInSection:) specify that returning a size of (0, 0) will result in no footer being added, this only seems to work when using `reloadData`. If using `performBatchUpdates` as you are, it will crash.

Answer (score 1):

[[_collectionView collectionViewLayout] invalidateLayout];

It solves my problem: hide the footer then animate by performBatchUpdates.

and answer is from [Saren Inden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21912620/1685787)