# invalidateLayout with invalidateSupplementaryElements and UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am trying to refresh a Footer ( supplementaryElement). I am using the `invalidatelayout` method. Based on SO suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831035/reload-uicollectionview-header-or-footer). Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewlayoutinvalidationcontext).

I am getting the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'the invalidation context
>   () sent to
>   -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout invalidateLayoutWithContext:] is not an instance of type UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext or a
>   subclass'

Implemented Code:

```
let footer_context = UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext()
footer_context.invalidateSupplementaryElements(ofKind: "ActivitiesSelectMembersFooterView", at: [indexPath])
self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout(with: footer_context)
```

Looks like `invalidateLayout` method is expecting `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext` instead of `UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext`.

I am using Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

My Storyboard in Xcode is here -

[image]

"Next" is the Footer that has the custom class "ActivitiesSelectMembersFooterView"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message accurately describes the problem.  When calling `invalidateLayout(with:)` on a UICollectionViewFlowLayout object, you need to pass  an instance of [UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayoutinvalidationcontext).

Change this line:

```
let footer_context = UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext()
```

To this:

```
let footer_context = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext()
```